# Guzzle is very slow to access local webpage

Tags: curl, phpunit, localhost, guzzle

I'm just getting started with `Guzzle` for acceptance testing an API using `PHPUnit`. The API resides on my local machine, but still the response time for `Guzzle` is ~5 seconds! When I'm using a browser it loads the website "instantly", leading me to believe that it's a problem with either `Guzzle` or `cURL`.

Here is my test unit:

```
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /** @var  GuzzleHttp\Client */
    private $http;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->http = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://test-site.local']);
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
        $this->http = null;
    }

    public function testGet() {
        $response = $this->http->request('GET', 'users');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

        $contentType = $response->getHeaders()["Content-Type"][0];
        $this->assertStringStartsWith("application/json", $contentType);
    }
}
```

What could cause the long response time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was related to using [`.local`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) as the top level domain for my local test URL. Apparently, `.local` is used by Bonjour services on Mac OSx, somehow causing interference with cURL (but not with browsers oddly enough).  There is a similar [question on the Superuser StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/539849/long-lookup-times-for-local-in-hosts-file).

Solved it by editing my `hosts` file and virtual hosts configuration to use `.dev` instead of `.local`:

```
protected function setUp() {
    $this->http = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://test-site.dev']);
}
```